# 'Market report news' or 'market reports news'

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I'm new here. Can anyone help please?

Which one of these is correct: *market report news* or *market reports news*?

Examples:

> Have you checked that market report news?
>
> Have you checked all market reports news?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Market report news.

I suspect the reason has to do with the awkward pronunciation we'd be dealing with if there were the S.

Answer (score 0):

"Market report news" is more grammatical ; in any noun adjunct the first part of the combination needs to be singular . In this phrase you have two noun adjuncts 
1: Market Report , where the noun market modifies the noun report 
2: Market Report + news , where the noun phrase "market report" modifies the noun news .

similar examples :
Language school : even if it teaches several languages 
7 Man Army , was a very popular movies in the 1970s